# Finding two parts in URL with Regex

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I have bunch of landing page urls with some variabel data in between.
I need to tell Google tag manager with Regex that the url must contain the first part AND the 2nd part of the url to make it a match.

Everything between the 1st and 2nd part and everything after part 2 is variabel and should pass.

```
https://shop.domein.nl/checkout/first-part-to-capture-{{variabel-data}}/2ndpart-to-capture{{?variabel-data}}
```

In this example that would be:
first part:
`https://shop.domein.nl/checkout/first-part-to-capture-`

2nd part:
`2ndpart-to-capture`

Can someone help me creating the right regex.
If you could post an example on https://regex101.com/

That would be awesome :)

Thanks

Comment: The universal way: `https://shop.domein.nl/checkout/(first-part-to-capture)-\{\{.*\}\}/(2ndpart-to-capture)`. You might need to escape slashes (/) too. You will get 2 groups with the captures.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you want everything except `/` after the begining of a known url.
You don't even need to know {{variable-data1}} and {{variable-data2}}.

`(https:\/\/shop\.domein\.nl\/checkout\/[^\/]+){{.+}}\/([^\/]+){{.+}}`

avec:

- `https:\/\/shop\.domein\.nl\/checkout\/` your known url
- `[^\/]+` anything except `/` as many times as needed (>=1 character)
- `{{.+}}` anything between 2 brackets (>=1 character)

Check if it does the job:
https://regex101.com/r/4dcltc/3